# Not able to access internet on my Ubuntu 17.04, for a wifi network that uses static ip configuration

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, 17.04

As stated in the subject internet is not working on my ubuntu 17.04 while connecting to my wifi. My internet provider requires a static ip configuration and thus the wifi router is configured using that. I'm able to access internet using any other wifi network on the same ubuntu laptop. Also the same wifi configuration is working fine with my other laptops. So I think I'll have do some configuration in the ubuntu to get it working.

Comment: Try this: https://youtu.be/o9fJWDoX4nE

Comment: The problem is not that my laptop is not getting an IP, it's just that it's not able to access the internet. My wifi router has a static IP configuration provided by the ISP and I think that is the problem, but the same configuration works for other devices very well.

Comment: The address that the router uses to access the internet is static, but aren't the addresses the router gives to all the connected devices DHCP? 192.168.1.13 for example? I'm not sure I see how the static IP address is significant to the Ubuntu computer.

Comment: You're correct and the address assigned is something similar like 192.168.0.*, Also the internet is working if I connect with my phone hotspot.